# Deleting a node and dealing with the new nullptr and linked node

Tags: c++, queue, nodes, pairing

So I have a queue with a root node. Each node has a child or a sibling. The root can have multiple children but only points to one *child* node. That child can have children, but it will also have other siblings. These siblings are all children of the root node. And the last child, who has no sibling after it, we call the parent node its sibling, so the root.

What I'm having a problem with is when I want to remove the parent node. I have to loop through children until there's none left. If I do if(currNode->sibling), this works for ALL CHILDREN. but it shouldn't I thought it should break the if statement if the sibling is the root. Because before I do this cycling, I do delete root. And then root = nullptr. So why does the child whose sibling is the root still point to a valid location and not nullptr? Thanks a ton

Comment: please show the code it will be a lot easier. Probably u are not creating variable in a heap(with new keyword)..

Comment: Pointers are one way. A points at B. B has no clue it's being pointed at. Think about what a nightmare it would be to have to track all of the potential pointers pointing at a variable. Yuck. Anyway, `root` points at a node. Removing this node and nulling `root` cannot also null the sibling's pointer to `root`s node. because `root` has no idea who else is pointing at the same node.

Comment: ah I see! That's very confusing. So I took that into account and didn't delete root initially. I just checked if sibling != root. This condition was easily met and seemed more proper. Thanks for the help!

Comment: maybe u can try pointer to a pointer(**).  currNode->sibling = &root; and if root is nullptr, *currNode->sibling will also be nullptr.

Comment: @user2971569 thanks, I'll try that and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Draw it out on paper. A parent node cannot be a sibling of its own children.  So your statement that "*the last child, who has no sibling after it, **we call the parent node its sibling, so the root***" is just plain wrong. If you are somehow actually doing that, stop doing that.  The last node has no siblings after it, and no children beneath it.

When removing a node, *looping* through its siblings is wrong. You have to loop through its *children* instead, and only *update* its immediate siblings to point at each other, as they will now be new siblings after the removal is complete.

Try something like this:

```
struct node
{
    node *parent;
    node *children;
    node *previous;
    node *next;
    ...

    node() :
        parent(0), children(0), previous(0), next(0), ...
    {}

    ~node()
    {
        unlink();
        while (children)
            delete children;
    }

    void unlink()
    {
        if (previous)
            previous->next = next;

        if (next)
            next->previous = previous;

        if ((parent) && (parent->children == this))
            parent->children = next;

        parent = next = previous = 0;
    }

    void addChild(node *child)
    {   
        child->unlink();

        child->parent = this;
        if (children)
        {
             node *t = children;
             while (t->next)
                 t = t->next;
             child->previous = t;
             t->next = child;
        }
        else
            children = child;        
    }

    ...
};

class myqueue
{
private;
    node *root;
    ...

public:
    myqueue() :
        root(new node)
    {}

    ~myqueue()
    {
        delete root;
    }

    void addChild(node *parent = 0)
    {
        node n = new node;

        if (!parent)
             parent = root;

        parent->addChild(node);
    }

    void remove(node *n)
    {
        delete n;
    }

    ...
};
```